# Where to ask question about best software in some category

Tags: discussion, stack-overflow

On which stackoverflow site I should ask a question where I need to get some opinion from people about the best software/app they have used in some category.

Like, for example, best webapp in creating mockups

Regards

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Generally [SU](http://superuser.com) is good for a general application questions, but webapps happen to be an exception there, so your best bet is probably the [Web Apps Stack Exchange site](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/). You can also try an SE site for the specific category you're interested in; creating mockups might fall under the [User Interface](http://area51.stackexchange.com/proposals/5728/user-interface) proposal, but they're not in beta yet

Comment: what about iphone apps?

Comment: SU doesn't do software recommendation questions. [Guide on MSU](http://meta.superuser.com/questions/5372/how-do-i-ask-a-question-that-may-require-recommending-software).

Comment: Isn't [Software Recommendations](https://softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/) the correct SE site?